# Avoid grepping all in boolean context

Tags: perl, grep

Its a pitty that grep function in perl cant recognize "boolean" context, because  in Perl there is no "boolean" context at all.

So if i do something like this

```
print "matched\n" if grep { print "$_\n"; $_&1 } 1..31
```

numbers from 1 to 31 will be printed instead of only "1" which is enough to get "true" result in "if".

to avoid this behaviour i have to do something awful:

```
print "matched\n" if do { my $fl; $_&1 and $fl=1, last for 1..31; $fl }
```

Maybe it can be done in a simplest way? Is there some fast XS code implementing "boolean grep" on CPAN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everyone seems to forget they can write subs to hide "awful" details.

```
sub any(&@) { my $cb = shift; for (@_) { return 1 if $cb->() } 0 }

say "match" if any { say; $_ & 1 } 1..31;
```

That said, `any` is already provided by [List::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Util). (Also check out [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils).)

Note that the list of item over which to iterate will still be placed entirely on the stack before `any` is called. That's rather cheap compared to needlessly calling a sub multiple times, but it could still be an issue for you. I believe that's the problem [List::Gen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Gen) tries to address.

Comment: (Heh, I just noticed "cb" has two valid interpretations: "code block" and "callback".)

Comment: Dont know what about "any", but "first" seems to be less effective than simple "for": https://pastebin.com/8cWjf7Cx

Comment: @drvtiny, I never said it was faster (for a list of a given size). That wasn't what you asked for. Subroutine calls are expensive, and your check is extremely cheap. /// `for (@a)` is specifically optimized. Try `for ((), @a)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (i voted for it and will mark as a resolution). Strange that first() in XS'ed List::Util is so slow :(

Comment: As I just mentioned, Perl subroutine calls are slow. Making the call from XS doesn't change that. (Well, technically, it actually does help, because it means MULTICALL can be used to speed up multiple calls to the same sub by delaying the freeing of temps. But only so much.)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a tool seeking a job rather than a job seeking a tool. If the task is to go through a list of numbers and stop when you find one that meets a condition, don't use something that by design wants to inspect every element:

```
foreach my $n ( @n ) {
    say $n;
    if( $n & 1 ) {
        say 'Matched!";
        last;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

grep is able to cheat; the block that it executes isn't actually a subroutine and it is able to run it much faster than if it were, and non-grep alternatives are stuck doing a sub call.

IMO unless you have a very long list and are likely to find the desired match towards the beginning, there's no reason not to just use grep.  Or at least, the reason of making your code more readable (which using "any" or such may do) outweighs any performance gain (or loss).